# Python Sort() method

Tags: python

I am starting to learn Python.

Can someone explain why sort() returns None?

```
alist.sort()            ## correct
alist = blist.sort()    ## NO incorrect, sort() returns None
```

Why shouldn't

```
alist = blist.sort()
```

return the sorted list and give it back to alist? This does not make sense to me.

Thanks.

Comment: `sorted('FMRT', key=lambda x: ord(x) % 16)`

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 11):

`alist.sort()` sorts `alist` in-place, modifying `alist` itself.

If you want a new list to assign somewhere, use `blist = sorted(alist)`

- `list.sort()`: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types
- `sorted()`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
alist = sorted(blist)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to perform the sorting on same list then you have to use `sort()` method of list. But If you dont want to change the sequence of original list but you need a sorted copy of the original list then use `sorted()` inbuilt function.