# Why python sort function for string list does not work

Tags: python

```py
print(['at', 'from', 'hello', 'hi', 'there', 'this'].sort())
```

returns

```
None
```

1: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-list-sort-tutorial-examples/ 
2: [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

I saw two examples, but why not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408050/python-sort-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort()` doesn't have return value, so it return default `None`. It modifies the original list, so you need to use it on a list name

```
l = ['at', 'from', 'hello', 'hi', 'there', 'this']
l.sort()
print(l)
```

If you don't want do modify the list you can create sorted copy with `sorted()`

```
l = ['at', 'from', 'this', 'there', 'hello', 'hi']
print(sorted(l)) # prints sorted list ['at', 'from', 'hello', 'hi', 'there', 'this']
print(l) # prints the original ['at', 'from', 'this', 'there', 'hello', 'hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the function `sort()` and where it works. `sort()` will only act upon a mutable data type, which must be a list or something like it. It has no return, it only modifies a data type. This is why it will return a sorted list, as the list has passed through the `sort()` function. When you run this program:

```py
>>> i = ['at', 'from', 'hello', 'hi', 'there', 'this']
>>> i.sort()
>>> print(i)
['at', 'from', 'hello', 'hi', 'there', 'this']
>>>
```

It works fine, as the `sort()` function is being called to a variable.